# Proving that a = -a?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

OK, so I think I found a crazy way to prove that any number is equal to its opposite.

Start with this equation: $$a = a$$

Divide by b: $${a\over  b} = {a \over b}$$

Multiply by $-1$: $${-a \over b} = {a \over -b}$$

Take Square Roots: $${i\sqrt a \over \sqrt b} = {\sqrt a \over i\sqrt b}$$

Multiply by $\sqrt b$: $$i\sqrt a = \sqrt a / i$$

Multiply by i: $$i^2\sqrt a = \sqrt a$$

Divide by $\sqrt a$: $$i^2 = 1$$

This proves 1 of 2 things that lead to each other:
$$i = 1 \text{or} -1 = 1$$

This proof can't be true...but why?

Comment: Hi, @user560, welcome to math.SE. Please consider formatting your equations with MathJax, as it makes it much easier for us to read. Here's a guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 9):

Take Square Roots: i√a / √b = √a / i√b

Every non-zero complex number has two square roots, one of them is always the other one multiplied by $-1$.

In this step you took two different roots.

Comment: I get the first part, that every complex number has two roots/conjugates, but what do you mean by taking two different roots?

Comment: @user560 On each side of the equation you've chosen a different root. You'd have to have chosen the same root on each side for that to be valid. You can say that $4=4$ implies $2=2$ or $-2=-2$ but not $2=-2$.

Comment: In essence, taking square roots is not a well defined function in the complex numbers and so it makes no sense to say $a=b$ implies $\sqrt{a}=\sqrt{b}$ because $\sqrt{a}$ is not even well defined.

Comment: Let me give you an example: Clearly John = John, since Anne and Tom are both friends of tom we have Anne = Tom. now replace friend with square root and replace John with $a/b$ and Anne with $\frac{i\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$ and Tom with $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{i\sqrt{b}}$

Comment: However, aren't Anne and Tom different in their own way? EDIT: I got it :) thanks

Comment: yes, but so are $\frac{i\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{i\sqrt{b}}$. In fact if you add them you get $0$, because $\frac{1}{i}=-i$.

Comment: $a=b\;\Rightarrow\;\left(\sqrt{a}=\sqrt{b}\right)\;\vee\;\left(\sqrt{a}=-\sqrt{b}\right)$ would be the implication to use in such cases. Edit: that is if you have some kind of "root picking" algorithm, easy on real numbers, not easy on complex...

Comment: if $\frac{1}{i}={-i}$, then doesn't that prove that $\frac{i \sqrt{a} }{\sqrt{b} }=\frac{-i \sqrt{a} }{\sqrt{b} }$? Edit: I'm sorry for all of the comment edits, I'm trying to get used to the format :)